# Rest API returns an empty list when connecting to database using JDBC ignoring the data brought from the database

Tags: java, jdbc, jax-rs

Im doing a project on my own and the point of the project is to make an a rest API in java and bring data from database using JDBC. The problem is when i make the connection and retrieve the data using main method everything works fine but when i try to retrieve the data through a get request, it returns an empty list. This is the endpoint

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {
UserService userService = new UserService();

@GET
@Path("/all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllUsers() throws InterruptedException {
    List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
    GenericEntity<List<User>> wrapper = new GenericEntity<List<User>>(users) {
    };
    return Response.ok(wrapper).build();
}
```

}

And this is the class that connects to database using JDBC

```
public class ConnectionJDBC {

private static String USERNAME = "root";
private static String PASSWORD = "root";
private static String CONSTRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
private static String DATABASE = "users_db";

static Connection connection;

public ConnectionJDBC() {
}

public static Connection getConnectionToDB() {
    try {
        String url = CONSTRING + DATABASE;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connection faild");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Something went wrong before establishing the connection");
    }
    return connection;

}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    connection = getConnectionToDB();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM users_db.user_info;";
    List<User> userListRetrived = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet dataRetrieved = statement.executeQuery();
        while (dataRetrieved.next()) {
            User user = new User(dataRetrieved.getInt("id"), 
                    dataRetrieved.getString(2),
                    dataRetrieved.getString(3));
            userListRetrived.add(user);
            return userListRetrived;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Something went wrong when retriving the data");
    }
    return userListRetrived;

}
```

}

UserService class is here

```
public class UserService {
private ConnectionJDBC connectionJDBC = new ConnectionJDBC();

public UserService() {
}

public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    ConnectionJDBC connectionJDBC = new ConnectionJDBC();
    List<User> usersList = connectionJDBC.getUsers();
    return usersList;
}
```

}

The user class is a normal java bean. It feels like getUsers method is ignoring bringing the data from the database and instead it returns the instantiated empty list instead. I'm using jersey and deploying the project on Glassfish.
Any clues on how i can fix that or explanation for this situation?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be getting exception - check for string "Something went wrong when retriving the data" on console.

Comment: Well it gave me this warning: WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

Comment: Where's UserService?

Comment: Oh sorry i just added it!  @Paul Samsotha

Comment: Have you done any debugging to check the list after it is retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't invoke `userService.getUsers()` method from userResource() class. Please update your code in `userResource()` class as follows

```
GenericEntity<List<User>> wrapper = new GenericEntity<List<User>>(userService.getUsers());
```

Comment: Well i already did that when i created a new list called users:     List<User> users = userService.getAllUsers();
    GenericEntity<List<User>> wrapper = new GenericEntity<List<User>>(users) {
    };